# How To Use FB NativeAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, facebook-ads-api

I am a beginner at android. I am creating a news app which parses data from JSON and display it in recyclerview. I want to place facebook native ads between recycler view. I found a library for integrating FB native ads with recyclerview. but I don't know how to use it. Please help.

Library Link
https://github.com/ldt116/FBNativeAdAdapter

Comment: This library doesn't seem to get any updates anymore and the current version doesn't work with the current facebook library.

Answer (score 0):

first you create your own customized Adapter
then instead of passing it to your recycler view you should pass it to FBNativeAdAdapter then you pass the FBNativeAdAdapter to your recycler view

```
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();//create your own adapter
    FBNativeAdAdapter fbAdapter = FBNativeAdAdapter.Builder.with("469109283477914_473204296401746", adapter)
            .build();// pass it to fbAdapter 

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));//create layout manager and pass it to recyclerview
    rv.setAdapter(fbAdapter); //pass fbadapter to recycler view
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer. Butwhen i try to do this my app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
     FbNativeAdAdapter nativeadpater = FbNativeAdAdapter.Builder.with("your placement Id", recycleradapter).adIteminterval(addintervalnumberwhereyouwanttoshowad).build();

rv.setadapter(nativeadpater);
```

Comment: do i want to create a native ad layout xml file. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes you have to create two layout file for native ad one for container and another one for native ad layout

Comment: i am a beginner please explain. thanks for your reply.